# ejs : Could not find the include file

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, ejs

localhost is totally fine but an error at Heroku

```
Error: /app/views/pages/explorer/explorer.ejs:1

<%- include('../../partials/head.ejs') %> <%- include('../../partials/alerts.ejs') %>

Could not find the include file "../../partials/head.ejs"
```

[localhost is totally fine but an error at Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeIv5.png)

Comment: Can you post the file structure of your project?

Comment: Thank you so much for coming forward to help me..
There was a small problem that I found after a lot of searching.